# Issues with multiple messages being published to same pub sub topic

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

We are trying to publish messages to a google pub sub topic and I am using the sample code from the this git [repository](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/82e4d0d2753283d3bab4b6480a965e4706729003/samples/snippets/src/main/java/pubsub/PublisherExample.java).

The issue here is that whenever even a single message is being published from below code there is exponential rise in number of duplicate messages being published to the topic.
Not sure why I are facing this behavior but not able to figure out if there is an issue with sample code or pub sub topic that has been created.
Could someone help me understand what is going on here and how to fix this issue.

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String topicId = "your-topic-id";

    publisherExample(projectId, topicId);
      }

       public static void publisherExample(String projectId, String topicId)
      throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);

    Publisher publisher = null;
    try {
      // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();

      String message = "{\r\n" + 
                    "   \"errorCodeFormat\": \"NF-123-ABC000\"\r\n" + 
            "}";
      ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
      PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data).build();

      // Once published, returns a server-assigned message id (unique within the topic)
      ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
      String messageId = messageIdFuture.get();
      System.out.println("Published message ID: " + messageId);
    } finally {
      if (publisher != null) {
        // When finished with the publisher, shutdown to free up resources.
        publisher.shutdown();
        publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      }
      }
    }
     }
```

Below is the Subscriber code being used

```java
public static void subscribeAsyncExample(String projectId, String subscriptionId) throws TimeoutException {
    ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
        ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
    
    

    // Instantiate an asynchronous message receiver.
    MessageReceiver receiver =
        (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
          // Handle incoming message, then ack the received message.
          System.out.println("Id: " + message.getMessageId());
          System.out.println("Data: " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
          consumer.ack();
        };

        System.out.println("You are in consumer listener");

        Subscriber subscriber = null;
       //        try {
          subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
          // Start the subscriber.
          subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
          System.out.printf("Listening for messages on %s:\n", subscriptionName.toString());
          // Allow the subscriber to run for 30s unless an unrecoverable error occurs.
          subscriber.awaitTerminated(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
      //        } catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
    //          // Shut down the subscriber after 30s. Stop receiving messages.
    //          subscriber.stopAsync();
    //        System.out.println("Subscriber state: {}"+ subscriber.state());

//  }
  }
```

Comment: How are you determining that "there is exponential rise in number of duplicate messages being published to the topic"? Is it that your subscriber is receiving the messages many times or are you using metrics on the topic? If the former, can you share your subscriber code?

Comment: @Kamal Aboul-Hosn when i say exponential its for every 1 message published using above code I see random 5 to 7 duplicate messages on topic. I will update subscriber code above for your reference

Comment: Do the duplicate messages have different message IDs or the same ID?

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn the message id's are different for duplicate messages but the payload data remains the same. One behaviour i found was that the published message id is always matching the last of the duplicate message

Answer (score 1):

Given that these messages have different message IDs, this indicates that the duplication is happening on the publish side. There could be three causes of this:

1. Extra, unexpected calls being made to `publish`.
2. Retries at the application level.
3. Retries within the Pub/Sub client library.

The code that you have shown doesn't really indicate that either of the first two things is happening, though if your code is actually more complex, e.g., calls publish in a loop, then it is worth checking to ensure that neither of these two is the case.

For the last one, the Pub/Sub client library internally retries publishes that fail with retryable reasons. One of the most typical reasons would be a `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error, which occurs when the client does not receive a response quickly enough from the server. This can result in duplicates as both the initial request and the retried request could ultimately succeed and you would only get the message ID back from the second request.

A `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error could happen for many different reasons. It could be that your internet connection is slow and results in the inability to transfer the message and receive the response quickly enough. The slowness may not be the connection itself; if you are running on machine that is doing lots of other things over the network, it could be that the connection is saturated and therefore the request and response can't get processed in a timely fashion. If you are running through a proxy, that could contribute as well.

It could also be that the machine is overloaded in terms of RAM or CPU. If there is a lot of paging that needs to happen or the CPU is fully utilized, then the callbacks that need to be processed by the client library may not be handled in time, resulting in `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` errors and a retry of the message.

Since the messages are ultimately succeeding, you could probably fix this by [changing the parameters to how the requests are retried](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#retry) to increase the initial timeout:

```
import com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;
...

    Publisher publisher = null;
    try {
      // Create a publisher instance with default settings bound to the topic
      // Retry settings control how the publisher handles retry-able failures
      Duration initialRetryDelay = Duration.ofMillis(100); // default: 100 ms
      double retryDelayMultiplier = 2.0; // back off for repeated failures, default: 1.3
      Duration maxRetryDelay = Duration.ofSeconds(60);
      // This one is the important one to set.
      Duration initialRpcTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(60);
      double rpcTimeoutMultiplier = 1.0;
      Duration maxRpcTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(600);seconds
      Duration totalTimeout = Duration.ofSeconds(600);

      RetrySettings retrySettings =
          RetrySettings.newBuilder()
              .setInitialRetryDelay(initialRetryDelay)
              .setRetryDelayMultiplier(retryDelayMultiplier)
              .setMaxRetryDelay(maxRetryDelay)
              .setInitialRpcTimeout(initialRpcTimeout)
              .setRpcTimeoutMultiplier(rpcTimeoutMultiplier)
              .setMaxRpcTimeout(maxRpcTimeout)
              .setTotalTimeout(totalTimeout)
              .build();
      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setRetrySettings(retrySettings).build();
```

With the above settings, the initial RPC would be given 60s to complete. That should hopefully reduce the duplicates. If you are just experimenting right now, you may want to tweak these settings in your production environment as such a long timeout may not be necessary.